# How to get SelectList for the current user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get the selectlist of customers/products/categories from the database. the selectlist will only show the selectlist of customer/product/categories of the current user/current logged in user.

But I am only getting the first item belonging to the current logged user.

In the database, each users has applicationUserId

I am supposed to get all the list of customer/category/product of the current user in a selectlist

```
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
            var currentUser = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers.Where(c => c.ID == currentUser.Id), "ID", "Name") ;


            ViewData["ProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == currentUser.Id), "ProductId", "ProductName");


            ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.Categories.Where(p =>p.CategoryId == currentUser.Id) , "CategoryId", "CategoryName");

            return View();
        }
```

Updated code

```
 public IActionResult Create()
        {
            var currentUser = _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

            string userId = currentUser.Id.ToString();
            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers.Where(c => c.ApplicationUserId == userId), "ID", "Name");

            ViewData["ProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.Categories.Where(p => p.ApplicationUserId == userId), "ProductId", "ProductName");

            ViewData["ProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.Products.Where(p => p.ApplicationUserId == userId), "ProductId", "ProductName");

            return View();
        }
```

after updating the code, I got

```
InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.
```

Comment: What is the return type of `_userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);` ? Is it task? Also, are you that the error occures in this code? Can you debug and make sure it ?

Answer (score 3):

The foreign key you used in your query is wrong.

```
ViewData["ProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.Products.Where(p => p.ProductId == currentUser.Id), "ProductId", "ProductName");
```

instead of this it should be like,

```
ViewData["ProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.Products.Where(p => p.UserId == currentUser.Id), "ProductId", "ProductName");
```

The field name depends on your table structure.

Comment: When I did this `ViewData["ProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.Products.Where(p => p.applicationUserId == currentUser.Id), "ProductId", "ProductName"); `  I got error `operator "==" cannot be applied to operand 'string' and 'int' `

Comment: I believe your applicationUserId defined as string then? So you can do something like `string userId = currentUser.Id.ToString(); ViewData["ProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.Products.Where(p => p.applicationUserId == userId), "ProductId", "ProductName");`

Comment: Now I am matching the store id and the current userId. It works for one but when I added the other selectlist code,  I got `InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.'

Comment: Can you update the question with the code? It will be more easy to follow up

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not awaiting the first query, so the subsequent queries are being issued before the first has been completed. In other words, you need to add the `await` keyword.

```
var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

However, since all you're after here is the user's id, it's not necessary to go to the database for that. Just do:

```
var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine now. I added updated the return to async Task `public async Task<IActionResult> Create()`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
The two suggestions from @serdar and @chris-pratt helped me to fix my code.

I later came out with

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
        {
            var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

            string userId = currentUser.Id.ToString();
            ViewData["CustomerId"] = new SelectList(_context.Customers.Where(c => c.ApplicationUserId == userId), "ID", "Name");

            ViewData["CategoryId"] = new SelectList(_context.Categories.Where(p => p.ApplicationUserId == userId), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");

            ViewData["ProductId"] = new SelectList(_context.Products.Where(p => p.ApplicationUserId == userId), "ProductId", "ProductName");



            return View();
        }
```